# Detect when textfield has been pressed in swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I want to have an action when a certain textfield is pressed. I have tried

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == myTextField {
        print("pressed")
    }
}
```

but this didn't work for me. Does anyone have any solutions? Thanks

Comment: What happening with this ?

Comment: nothing is printed when the textfield is pressed

Comment: Did you set the text field's delegate?

Comment: @rmaddy is right, check first of delegate connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is the callback from UITextFieldDelegate. But it will only be fired if the class with this is connected to your UITextField's delegate.

simple Example using an iOS ViewController:

```
class yourViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    /* Make sure that your variable 'myTextField' was created using an IBOutlet from your storyboard*/
    @IBOutlet var myTextField : UITextField!

    override func ViewDidLoad()
    {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         myTextField.delegate = self // here you set the delegate so that UITextFieldDelegate's callbacks like textFieldDidBeginEditing respond to events
    }



    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    if textField == myTextField {
    print("pressed")
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure though that you understand the concept of the delegation pattern event handling, and how a delegate captures and posts events like this one for instance. A lot of Cocoa GUI components use this design. these are some useful links.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/26/what-is-delegation-a-swift-developers-guide/

Comment: If the text field is an outlet, it's common to set the delegate in the storyboard instead of setting in code.

Comment: great, that fixed the problem, missed out the textfield delegate. Thank you!